# What does it mean when there are two functions with the 'arrow function indicator' between them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have seen arrow function examples like this:

```
people.forEach((person) => {
  console.log(person.id + person.name);
});
```

and this all makes sense to me. But what does this mean?

```
dispatch = (action) => {
      this.setState((state) => reducer(state, action));
    }
```

It looks like `action` is the parameter passed to dispatch() and then what happens in the body of the function? Does it take the result of reducer and set the state? If so, why? What is the syntax?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes.It's executing the functions from the inside out so you could have `func1 = (val) => func2 () => do something with val`. Func 2 will be executed and return to func 1 as a value. Then func 1 is executed. You can also do something like `func1(func2(val))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know what this concept is called?

Comment: @FrancoisCarstens Thats not actually the case here. `setState` is accepting a function *reference* as its argument, not the *return value* of the function. `setState` was just created with the flexibility to accept either an object or a function. Its not really any special concept, its just one function being passed as an argument to another function. So they are not really called inside out. `setState` is called first, and then **internally** it is calling the function passed in and using it as the new state.

Comment: So the end result is this order of execution: `dispatch` -> `setState` -> `anonymous callback` -> `reducer`.

Comment: @BrianThompson, thank you for the clarification, `completing execution` may have been a better term. @user12809744 you're looking for `nested functions` and you may also be interested in learning about closures. funfunfunction has a nice video about that on Youtube. Here's an example of how this works. https://jsbin.com/qosujivime/edit?js,console. I've added the nested functions as variables since you can't console.log after a return. But it should give you an idea.

Comment: This all helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block of code is equivalent to the code below.

- `people.forEach` take one params which is a callback function
  Similar with the second block of code with `dispatch`

```js
const callback = (person) => {
  console.log(person.id + person.name);
}

people.forEach(callback);
```

The implementation of `dispatch` might be like this

```js
//Implementation
const dispatch = (callback) =>{
  const action = "something" // this might sth from somewhere, just get the idea of it
  callback(action)
}

// Similar to people.forEach we have
const callback = (action) => {
      this.setState((state) => reducer(state, action));
} 
dispatch(callback)
```

- They are called high-order function